# editText.requestFocus not working after notifyDataSetChanged of ListView (edittext on outside of listview)

Tags: android, listview, focus

I have a problem:

My Layout is simple only an editText and a listView (both of them is seperated). Not like other cases in other thread, my editText location is above of listView.

> And now i have problem, how to requestFocust to editText after
>   updating listView data via adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ?

i put requestFocus code here :

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
        {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    switch (keyCode)
                    {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:{
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

                            return true;
                        }
                        default:{
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    editText.requestFocus();
                    System.out.println("FOCUS GET");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

inside doAddToList last code is adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();. System.out.println result is several times show "FOCUS GET" on console but focus not get for EditText.

Comment: Please update your code. Where & How r u calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I already update my code, not full code but i think is already enough to explain my problem.

Comment: Your overall approach is wrong. You are setting focus to editText in editText's keyListener. Without focus keyListener will never fire and I think thats your problem. Please update your answer and write what you are trying to achieve then we can give you a alternate solution

Answer (score 2):

I think when you call notifyDataSetChanged() a lot of processing happens that's why your call to editText.requestFocus() is being ignored.

try using this code after notifyDataSetChanged() call

```
recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run(){
        editText.requestFocus();
     }
});
```

OR

```
editText.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run(){
        editText.requestFocus();
     }
});
```

EDIT : Try  (Adjust delay time as per your need)-

```
recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run(){
    editText.requestFocus();
 }
```

}, 1000);

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you explain how your code works ? thank you anyway.

Comment: If a lot of parallel processing is under way, because of limited resources android seems to ignore some method call. Post() method puts your block of code in a queue so that it will execute one by one. For more information see documentation. If this solves your problem mark this as answer

Comment: I already try your solution, but it's not working. Other solution please? thanks

Comment: I already try your newest solution. It not really good if someone update listview in high speed. It will loss focus.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the requestFocus in the onKeyListener.  First off-  very few keyboards in Android send key events (most use higher level APIs) so it will probably not fire anyway.  Only hardware buttons always send key events.  Secondly, even f the keyboard sent key events it would have to already be open and you typing for that line to be executed.

If you want to set the focus every time notifyDataSetChanged is called, put a call to setFocus after every time you call notifyDataSetChanged.  Putting it where you have it isn't even close to right, and I can't figure out your logic in thinking it would be.

Comment: By the way , i laready put requestFocus below of notifyDataSetChanged. Please look again to my post.

Comment: No you didn't.  You have it inside a key listener, which is a completely unrelated function (and probably not doing what you think it does anyway).

Comment: inside doAddToList last code is adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();. I mean inside doAddToList procedure i put adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();